# Phonegap splash screen not showing up

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, splash-screen, phonegap

After following the instructions I found here (http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/), I was unable to get the splash screen working for my Phonegap app.

I generated a number of splash screen files using https://www.resource-generator.com/. After following the official Phonegap documentation without success, I tried modifying my config.xml file, using information I found when looking around in several blog posts on the issue, but still was not able to get rid of the problem.

I am only building an Android app, so I am not looking to get this working in either iOS or Windows.

I hope someone can help me out here.

So my **config.xml** file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.[MY_NAME].hangman"
    versionCode = "1"
    version     = "1.0.0" >

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<name>
    [APP_NAME]
</name>

<description>
    [APP_DESCRIPTION]
</description>

<author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
    [MY_NAME]
</author>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" />

<!-- preferences -->
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
<preference name="orientation"      value="portrait" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />

<feature name="SplashScreen" >
    <param
            name="android-package"
            value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />

    <param
            name="onload"
            value="true" />
</feature>


<platform name="android">
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash src="splash.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" platform="android"  />
</platform>
```

and my app's folder structure is as follows (please follow the link):

http://www.wimverpoorten.com/Stackoverflow_folder_structure.PNG

I do not seem to be able to find the root of the problem here, hopefully someone can help me out. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in the meantime I found the issue.

In the config.xml file, it should not say **density="land-ldpi"** however it should say **qualifier="land-lpdi"** and likewise for all other lines with splash screen images in it.

I am glad I found this after searching a long time. I hope someone might benefit from seeing this answer at some stage.